# Find out what object is clicked, C#, unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a board game and I am stuck on something. Let's say the player rolls a 6. There are 3 possible moves for that and the player has to choose the tile where he wants the pawn moved by clicking on the tile. I don't know how to find out which tile the player clicked.

This is what I have in my Tile.cs script:

```
public Tile finalTile;

    void OnMouseUp()
    {
        finalTile = this;
    }
```

Pawn.cs script:

```
public Tile selectedTile;

Debug.Log(selectedTile.finalTile.transform.position);
```

I have assigned the script. The log shows the pawn, which I eventually understood, and it makes sense why. But I am still struggling, how can I do it? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to me. `OnMouseUp` method is called when player has released their mouse button after dragging the `gameObject` that script is attached to. You can print `gameObject.name` in this method and you will see what piece was dragged. You probably want to do some stuff while dragging them, so you will have to implement a class that each chess piece e.g. `Piece.cs` or `ChessPiece.cs` has, where you can implement [`IDragHandler`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IDragHandler.html) interface. Also your `Pawn.cs`, `Knight.cs`, `Bishop.cs` `Rook.cs`, `Queen.cs` and `King.cs` classes should probably be inherited from that class too. Also make sure you make a class where you will store information about current selected piece that you will change every time player has clicked on `ChessPiece` that's not already selected. I hope I have understood your issue correctly and it was helpful.